# Parsing and sorting alphanumeric element based on decimal substring

Tags: javascript

This is my array:

```
var arr=["Iteration 3.1","Iteration 3.2","Iteration 2.2","Iteration 2.3","Iteration 2.1"];
```

Expected Output is:

```
Iteration 3.2
Iteration 3.1
Iteration 2.3
Iteration 2.2
Iteration 2.1
```

I tried with:

```
arr.sort(function(a,b){
a=a.match(/[^a-zA-Z]/);
b=b.match(/[^a-zA-Z]/);
var an=parseFloat(a,10);
var bn=parseFloat(b,10);
return an<bn?1:(an>bn?-1:(a<b?-1:(a>b?1:0)));
});
```

What I currently get:

```
Iteration 3.1
Iteration 3.2
Iteration 2.2
Iteration 2.3
Iteration 2.1
```

[jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=b9UnxnB5AT)

Comment: try changing the expression to: /[^a-zA-Z ]/ (i.e. adding a space). parseInt doesn't like spaces. additionally, use parseFloat since parseInt will drop the period and decimals.

Comment: Tried it, doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

You want to match *multiple* characters - your regular expression only matches *one* character (using a class that includes more unwanted characters than numeric ones). Try this regular expression (which matches any whole or decimal-point numbers) instead: `/[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+/`

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me:

```
var arr=["Iteration 3.1","Iteration 3.2","Iteration 2.2","Iteration 2.3","Iteration 2.1"];
arr.sort(function(a,b){
    a=a.split(" ");
    b=b.split(" ");
    var an=parseFloat(a[1],10);
    var bn=parseFloat(b[1],10);
    return an<bn?1:-1;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   numeric = new Array();
function numOrdDesc(a, b){ return (b-a); } 
var arr=["Iteration 3.1","Iteration 3.2","Iteration 2.2","Iteration 2.3","Iteration 2.1", "Iteration 10.1"];

for (i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {

 numeric.push(parseFloat(arr[i].replace('Iteration ','')));

}

console.log(numeric.sort( numOrdDesc ));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xuXGv/1/

Help from here: http://javascript.about.com/library/blsort.htm. P.S. 'Iteration' string can be added easily... :)

Comment: As a character sort rather than a numeric sort, that breaks down at "Iteration 10.1".

Answer (score 0):

You can match the integer and decimal part of each item-

```
var arr=["Iteration 3.1","Iteration 3.2","Iteration 2.2",
"Iteration 2.3","Iteration 2.1"];

arr.sort(function(a, b){
    var a1= a.match(/\d+(\.\d+)?/),
    b1= b.match(/\d+(\.\d+)?/); 
    return b1[0]-a1[0];
});


/*  returned value: (Array)
Iteration 3.2, Iteration 3.1, Iteration 2.3, Iteration 2.2, Iteration 2.1
*/
```